# My website menu doesnt display correctly on IE

Tags: html, css

It's my first time here so please excuse me if I missed something even tough I've check a big amount of the posts here and something worked but didnt fixed completely the issue.

My main menu here: https://turbobeds.com/ works in all browsers except IE, where it displays the menu the first time I hover, and after that it displays only until the begining of the category title, I added as some guys here posted:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Also I already have HTML5SHIV:

```
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

I added `display: inline;` to both `#topCategories > ul > li` & `#topCategories > ul > li > a` and that fixed not displaying with displaying at hover. But still, if you just hover over the menu items not going lower it will display only  5px white space.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: Is this an Apache Server, IIS or ?  What does your Web Host use?

Comment: @PatsyIssa, I'm sorry but I don't know how to put that yet.

Comment: Which version(s) of IE? On what OS?

Comment: @Dave, I'm on Windows, any version of IE starting with 10. It displays the list of menu items only if I hover over them. If not, it displays the white margin of 5 px.

Comment: Your font is not loaded correctly in IE i think this can create problem.

Comment: @LoveTrivedi, I updated that with otf, ttf and wtf and for IE it loads the proper font, just takes a little more longer.

Comment: Whick version of IE. it works fine in ie9

Comment: @LoveTrivedi, please see this image. http://i.imgur.com/va8roGF.jpg

Comment: which version of IE showing this problem.

Comment: All versions of IE. If you dont hover on the submenu items only on the main nav you will see the issue too.

Comment: its working fine here http://i.imgur.com/hFLaxKI.png

Answer (score 0):

**I stand corrected, though you should still use the meta tag snippet in my answer below as your hover menu does not work at all in IE10 Compatibility Mode, I am experiencing the same issue you are in IE10 without Compatibility Mode turned on. The menu works on initial request, first time you hover but after that it does not display correctly. Anyway you can create a consolidated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your menu, just the HTML,CSS and Javascript only?**

Add this to your HTML in the `<head>` element:

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

The problem is that IE is in compatibility mode on your computer right now. Compatibility mode is a setting to get Internet Explorer to work better with certain websites by downgrading certain rendering features in IE to the previous version of IE, in your case IE9 but this does not mean IE10 is IE9 in compatibility mode. This will, for each page of you website that you include the meta tag on, change the clients IE settings to render as the latest installed version of IE with no band aids as what compatibility mode attempts to do. It will not change IE settings for any other website the client may visit.

You can also test in IE by hitting F12 and opening the Developer Tools. At the top of the developer tools window you will see a menu option called "Browser Mode" that allows you to quickly switch between "IE10 compatibility mode" and "IE10". In IE10 developer tools allos you to also switch to IE9,8, and & though I don't know how to true of a version of these browsers you get by doing this in an installed version of IE10.

Comment: Hello Brian, thank you for your answer. I've added that but unfortunately the same thing happen. Whenever I hover over the menu the first time it displays just fine, but when I hover the 2nd time only displays 5px of white space. Also as I said previous, I debuged with IE's developer tools and tried all versions, still the same happens. Regarding jsFiddle, I will try my best.

Comment: I'm trying to make a jSfiddle but this is OpenCart, and honestly I dont know how to separate HTML by php and to make it work. I've put the HTML of the nav + css without JS and it doesnt seem to work. Did you managed to fix it on your website?

Comment: Know I don' know why the menu is not working after you hover over it the first time, is the menu rendered by OpenCart or designed in OpenCart?

Comment: Mmmm, it's a custom theme designed for OpenCart. I guess is designed in.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the answer:

http://wonderwebware.com/blog/2013/02/28/how-to-fix-opencart-1-5-menu-bug-in-internet-explorer-10/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've updated the js file but the same thing happens. I'm out of ideas. This is very frustrating :) Did this worked for you?

Comment: Sorry that is best I got, not familiar with OpenCart